# ffmpeg replay input to output giving errors

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to stream something back out using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://xxx.114.173.196/live/ninja -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/test
```

but it is throwing the following output:

```
[flv @ 0x3e3e6e0] video stream discovered after head already parsed
[flv @ 0x3e3e6e0] audio stream discovered after head already parsed
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://xxx.114.173.196/live/ninja':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-1, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 62.50 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 120 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
[swscaler @ 0x3eb1180] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[flv @ 0x3f32780] FLV does not support sample rate 48000, choose from (44100, 22050, 11025)
[flv @ 0x3f32780] Audio codec mp3 not compatible with flv
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Function not implementedStream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> flv1 (flv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://xxx.114.173.196/live/ninja -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/test
```

The sample rate cannot be 48 kHz, which is triggering the absurd message that MP3 isn't compatible with FLV although that is its default codec.

This command should work, while avoiding transcoding:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://xxx.114.173.196/live/ninja -c copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/test
```